# I can still review in the CV queue after running out of CVs

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close, rate-limiting

Pretty minor (at least not pluralization…), but when I'm out of CVs ([image: 0 votes remaining]), it will still allow me to review in the queue:

[image: /review]

…even though I can't review First Posts and Late Answers without available up/down votes.

Comment: It would seem fitting to gray it out in a way similar to first posts and late answers, but this is definitely a minor bug.  I agree that it should be fixed, but it is probably not of the highest urgency since users really should know when they run out of close votes.

Comment: @Haney Is your edit implying that this was an intentional design change?  In the past users without close votes couldn't use the queue, so either this was intentionally changed, or this is a bug.

Comment: @Servy no, more that this is at a point of discussion it seems in that people on this question are deciding / deliberating on HOW it should work as opposed to WHAT needs doing.

Comment: It seems the code has a bug in it. It's *supposed* to be disabling the queue when you have no close votes remaining. Taking a look as it's clearly a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've patched up a logic bug in our code and the fix will be live in the next production release. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: So...to be clear: If I'm out of close **VOTES** I can no longer  review in the CVQ despite the 40 close **REVIEWS** I'm allowed?

Comment: Yep, that's how it is currently designed. Note that I didn't make that decision; merely fixed the incorrect logic around said decision.

Comment: Network wide, all sites.

Comment: Certainly, meta > rev `2014.7.16.2379`, network > rev `2014.7.16.1713`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I assume you guessed which way this would go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236650/let-me-handle-close-reviews-despite-running-out-of-close-votes

Comment: @rene no need to be sorry. My job is to be an advocate of the community. If that proposal gains traction then it's clearly a representation of what the community wants, and I'd be happy to implement it. I'm here to work with the community, not dictate it.

Comment: Thank you, this has bugged me for so long.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that it's not necessary to cast a close vote to do a review in the Close Votes queue; there are the **Leave Open** and **Edit** options. Thus, it is still possible to do 
reviews even when you run out of close votes (you'll just only be able to review posts you think should stay open).

Because of that, I'm not so sure that this is a bug.

Comment: Do you really think there should be people reviewing close votes who *cannot* vote to close when appropriate?

Comment: As long as they're not voting to leave open or editing instead of voting to close, it's not terrible. Not great, but not terrible. (I'll concede that reviewing while out of close votes is really annoying, especially since all you can do with the bad questions is "skip")

Comment: If we *do* decide that you can't review close votes if you don't have any close votes left, then that also brings up the question of whether you should be able to review VLQ if you don't have close votes or flags left.

Comment: This reasoning is inconsistent with the behavior of the other queues. You **could** use the "Late Answers" queue when you're out of votes and only flag flag-worthy posts, but that isn't allowed.

Comment: In support of Dennis I confess that I do handle close vote review tasks even when I have run out of close votes. It takes a lot of skipping to find reasonable posts that deserves a Leave Open vote. And I agree it is not a bug. If enough Leave Open votes are casted on a question it is removed from the queue which is a good thing. And I really hope those 7 upvoters on Code Gray's comment are all using their 40 tasks in the CVQ on a daily basis...